# How do I recreate the NetBeans Matisse form file?

Tags: swing, netbeans, matisse

I have swing code that was generated using NetBeans Matisse. Over time, the form file got lost. How do I recreate the Matisse form file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reverse engineer/recreate the .form file

Comment: Thanks Tim! Yes, it looks like I have to redo the screen.

Answer (score 0):

See [Netbeans: using GUI Builder on regular Java class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671778/netbeans-using-gui-builder-on-regular-java-class-file/1716852#1716852)

There is a FormGenerator utility that can usually regenerate a .form file from the .java file. It should work as long as the guarded blocks are largely unchanged